# Visual Studio 2013 Settings Manager GetReadOnlySettingsStore throws Exception

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing a Visual Studio Extension and need the list of Property Pages for a Given Category.

Given `"TextEditor"` the following list would be returned.

- General
- AllLanguages
- Basic
- CSharp
- etc.

The vs environment object `DTE` makes it easy to get the page properties, but provides no easy method to get all the pages.

```
vsEnvironment.get_Properties("TextEditor", pageName);
```

The values I'm after are actually stored in the registry however Visual Studio also provides the [Settings Store](http://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/ff460144%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) which I was hoping would help me get the list.

I've set it up like the following:

```
var settingsManager = new ShellSettingsManager(this); //ServiceProvider.GlobalProvider
var userSettingsStore = settingsManager.GetReadOnlySettingsStore(SettingsScope.UserSettings);
```

However `GetReadOnlySettingsStore` always throws the following exception.

```
The type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.SettingsScope' exists in both 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.12.0.dll' and 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.11.0.dll'
```

It looks like [Mads Kristensen has used this successfully](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2013/blob/master/EditorExtensions/CompatibilityChecker.cs) however I still can't tell what's wrong.

I would like to avoid bypassing the API's Visual Studio provides. So has anyone successfully used the `SettingsManager` or know another method to get the list?

Comment: Can you share the exception stack you're seeing? Also, there are other ways to enumerate languages which may or may not be more correct depending upon what you're trying to do.

Comment: I couldn't seem to get a stack trace, I executed the command in the immediate window and that's all I get back (no other exception information). What are the other ways to enumerate the languages?

Comment: There's several ways to enumerate. What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm allowing the user to select languages they want to export formatting settings for and loading them back in on a per-solution basis. This is the project (still very early days) https://github.com/Lavinski/VSSolutionSettings. The function `GetPropertyPages` is the related function.